# Int array sorting itself

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Paaohjelma {
    public static int pienin(int[] taulukko) {
        int temp, size;
        size = taulukko.length;

        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++ ){
            for(int j = i+1; j<size; j++){
                if(taulukko[i]>taulukko[j]){
                    temp = taulukko[i];
                    taulukko[i] = taulukko[j];
                    taulukko[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return taulukko[0];
    }
    
    public static int pienimmanIndeksi(int[] taulukko) {
        ArrayList<Integer> tauli = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i : taulukko) {
            tauli.add(i);
        }
        
        return tauli.indexOf(Paaohjelma.pienin(taulukko));
    }
    
    public static int pienimmanIndeksiAlkaen(int[] taulukko, int aloitusIndeksi) {
        // this methods should get the index of smallest value starting from specified index
        int[] tempTauli = taulukko;
        tempTauli = new int[tempTauli.length - aloitusIndeksi];
        
        // this gets the right values to temporary array
        if (aloitusIndeksi > 0) {
            int index = 0;
            int indexTauli = 0;
            for(int value : taulukko) {
                if(index >= aloitusIndeksi) {
                    tempTauli[indexTauli] = taulukko[index];
                    indexTauli++;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        // values added are automatically sorted from smallest to largest?
        // this shouldn't be, array should be 5, 99, 3, 12 but is shown as 3, 5, 12, 99
        for(int inty : tempTauli) {
            System.out.println(inty);
        }
        
        // get the index of smallest value in array
        // index is 0 should be 2
        int index = Paaohjelma.pienimmanIndeksi(tempTauli);
        
        // return index of smallest value (add starting index to get the index of smallest value in the original array when starting from specified index)
        return index+aloitusIndeksi;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test code
        int[] taulukko = {3, 1, 5, 99, 3, 12};
        int minIndex = Paaohjelma.pienimmanIndeksi(taulukko);
        System.out.println("Pienin: " + Paaohjelma.pienin(taulukko));
        System.out.println("Pienimmän indeksi: " + minIndex);
        System.out.println(Paaohjelma.pienimmanIndeksiAlkaen(taulukko, 2));
    }

}
```

Hello! I'm doing some programming course work for school and have been stuck in this particular part for couple hours. So I decided it would be best for someone else to take a look and provide some light why my approach for this problem isn't working.

**What should happen: class method PienimmanIndeksiAlkaen should return the index of smallest value in provided int array starting from specified index.**

The main problem I have been having is that the array seems to be automatically sorting itself and I have no idea what is possible causing this. **I have commented the relevant part of the code** and would be more than happy if someone could explain why this is happening and what possible could be done to prevent this.

Comment: im confused, why do you do something like Paaohjelma.function when the functions are static

Comment: @TruVortex_07 Test code comes straight from the course material, I have no idea.

Comment: The `pienin()` method sorts the array that you pass as a parameter. `pienimmanIndeksi()` calls the `pienin()` method with the array that you pass in, so after `Paaohjelma.pienimmanIndeksi(taulukko);` the `taulukko` array is sorted.

Comment: @Thomas Kläger My blindness continues, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your array is sorted is when you call

```
    System.out.println("Pienin: " + Paaohjelma.pienin(taulukko));
```

you sort the array.

When you pass the array into this function, you aren't actually passing the value of the array, but the *pointer* to the array - the address of the array in memory. This is the difference between passing parameters *by value* or *by reference*.

[image]

How do you know if the value is passed by value or by reference?
As a rule of thumb:

primitive values - i.e. int, double, etc. will be passed by value - their value will be copied and passed to the function.

Any other type, namely arrays and classes, will be passed by reference - the address of the value in memory will be passed to the function, thus any change to the value inside the function will affect it when the function ends too.

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: For objects, the references are _always_ passed [_by value_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @AlexRudenko Yes, the array variable stores the pointer to the array, and so when we pass the array we actually pass the address by value. I think that at this level it's better to obfuscate the details a bit in order to understand the basic difference in behavior between primitives and objects The link i provided describes what you mentioned in detail.